# Google language and site language dependancy

Tags: seo

I have a site with to languages, say English and German.
sitename.com/ - is for English
sitename.com/de/ - is for German

Currently the english speaking users that use Google.com, they type in the company name and see my site in the results with the link which points to sitename.com/ and has English description - that's good.

Now, german speaking users that search via google.de, they type company name but again...they see my site in results which points to sitename.com/ and has english description - not good. How do i make it point to sitename.com/de/ and have description in german lang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strongest geotargeting signal for Google is the top level domain. Unfortunately in your case you have a generic top level domain, but there are two things you can do to rank with the German section of your site on google.de:

1. **Set a geographic target for the /de/ subfolder in Google Webmaster Tools**. This is a two step process: first you verify your main .com domain in Google Webmaster Tools, than you can verify yourdomain.com/de/ as another website and set a a geographic target under *Site configuration* > *Settings* > *Geographic target*. [See more info about geotargeting](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399)
2. **Get links to the German section of your websites from German speaking websites**. How to get such links depends largely on your site topic, so I cannot give you a specific advice.